# Оформление кода. Вынос в классы

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace Database
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string line = "";

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("option.ini.txt", System.Text.Encoding.Default))
            {
                line = sr.ReadLine();
            }

            List<Person> employees = new List<Person>();
            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Person>));
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();

            if (line == "xml")
            {
                if (File.Exists("person.xml"))
                {
                    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("person.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                    {
                        List<Person> newEmployees = (List<Person>)xs.Deserialize(fs);
                        employees = newEmployees;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (line == "bin")
            {
                if (File.Exists("person.dat"))
                {
                    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("person.dat", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                    {
                        List<Person> newEmployees = (List<Person>)bf.Deserialize(fs);
                        employees = newEmployees;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (line == "bin" || line == "xml")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Установите значение bin или xml в файле option.ini.txt");
            }

            while (true)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Введите команду:");

                string com = Console.ReadLine();

                if (com.ToLower() == "exit")
                {
                    if (line == "xml")
                    {
                        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("person.xml", FileMode.Create))
                        {
                            xs.Serialize(fs, employees);
                        }
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("person.dat", FileMode.Create))
                        {
                            bf.Serialize(fs, employees);
                        }
                        return;
                    }
                }

                if (com.ToLower() == "allsee")
                {
                    if (line == "xml")
                    {
                        var res = employees.OrderBy(u => u.Name).ThenBy(u => u.Surname);
                        foreach (Person u in res)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Имя: {0} Фамилия: {1} Табельный номер: {2}", u.Name, u.Surname, u.PersonnelNumber);
                        }
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (line == "bin")
                    {
                        var res = employees.OrderBy(u => u.Name).ThenBy(u => u.Surname);
                        foreach (Person u in res)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Имя: {0} Фамилия: {1} Табельный номер: {2}", u.Name, u.Surname, u.PersonnelNumber);
                        }
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                if (com.ToLower() == "del")
                {
                    string t;

                    Console.WriteLine("Введите табельный номер сотрудника для удаления из базы:");
                    t = Console.ReadLine();

                    if (employees.Exists(p => p.PersonnelNumber == t))
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < employees.Count; i++)
                        {
                            if (employees[i].PersonnelNumber == t)
                            {
                                employees.Remove(employees[i]);
                            }
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("Удаление прошло успешно.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Сотрудника с таким табельным номером не существует!");
                    }
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    continue;
                }

                if (com.ToLower() == "add")
                {
                    string name;
                    string surname;
                    string personnelnumber;

                    Console.WriteLine("Введите имя сотрудника:");
                    name = Console.ReadLine();

                    Console.WriteLine("Введите фамилию сотрудника:");
                    surname = Console.ReadLine();

                    Console.WriteLine("Введите табельный номер сотрудника:");
                    personnelnumber = Console.ReadLine();

                    Person p = new Person(name, surname, personnelnumber);
                    employees.Add(p);

                    continue;
                }
                if (com.ToLower() != "add")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Доступные команды:");
                    Console.WriteLine("\tadd создать запись сотрудника");
                    Console.WriteLine("\tdel Удалить запись сотрудника");
                    Console.WriteLine("\tallsee Просмотреть список сотрудников");
                    Console.WriteLine("\texit Выйти и сохранить данные");
                    Console.ReadKey();

                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string PersonnelNumber { get; set; }
        public Person() { }

        public Person(string name, string surname, string personnelnumber)
        {
            Name = name;
            Surname = surname;
            PersonnelNumber = personnelnumber;
        }
    }
}
```

Как в данном коде вынести десериализацию и сериализацию отдельно в классы и управлять ими из данной менюшки?

Answer (score 1):

Могу предложить несколько шагов для реализации разбивки кода на компоненты.

1. Класс `MenuItem` - описывает один пункт меню, содержит название пункта меню и делегат типа `Action` для привязки конкретного действия к пункту меню. Для консольного меню полноценные события перебор, но это уже зависит от конкретной задачи и предпочтений.
2. Класс `Menu` - содержит список `MenuItem`-ов и отвечает за взаимодействие с пользователем, печать пунктов меню в заданном порядке и вызов привязанных к пунктам меню `Action`-ов.
3. Включите в отдельный класс или ваш класс `Person` методы вида `void SomeAction()` для реализации необходимых действий над сущностью.

Если вы хотите сохранить код меню в коде `Main`, то можно ограничиться выносом кода сериализации и десериализации в отдельные методы, которые разместить в текущем классе, либо отдельном классе, либо классе `Person` и заменить вынесенный в методы код на вызов созданных методов. Этот вариант более быстро реализуется, но менее гибок в дальнейшей работе.

Разумеется, это возможные, но не единственные варианты.

Если слишком увлечься ООП и паттернами проектирования, то из простой программы в 50-100 строк кода вполне можно раздуть монстра на пару десятков классов и пару тысяч строк кода, но надо ли все это в вашем случае или нет, решать вам. Если это фрагмент большой системы, возможно надо, если самостоятельная программа, то, скорее всего нет.